# Один класс вместо нескольких

Tags: ооп, веб-программирование, классы, php, cms

Я пишу cms на php и у меня там очень много классов, притом однотипных (есть класс для работы с новостями, статьями, отзывами, товарами т.д.) методы в этих классах тоже однотипны (получить данные об объекте, записать данные, получить список объектов и т.д.). По сути классы отличаются только набором полей и запросами внутри методов классов, а в остальном всё одинаковое... Жутко устал уже продолжать плодить эту уйму классов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может можно как то описать это всё в одном классе? Или я ещё думал создать родительский класс, но не знаю как это сделать, ведь у меня в классах разные поля, и все функции хоть с точки зрения алгоритма действуют и одинаково, но запросы во всех разные.... Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то поправить ситуацию или нужно так и делать???

Comment: Посмотрите active record в любом фреймворке

Comment: Если используете классы то используйте все доступные возможности, в Вашем случае наследование и полиморфизм. Базовый класс содержит общие методы. Дочерние расширяют(добавляют поля и тд) эти методы.

Comment: Если пишешь похожий код три раза - то это почти наверняка можно оптимизировать. Выглядит так как будто вам нужен базовый абстрактный класс с некоторым общим скелетом и отнаследовать от него остальные

Answer (score 1):

Любой фреймворк содержит кучу классов, которые помогают упростить код и ускорить разработку.

Пример: [пошаговый пример создания блога на базе фреймворка Yii Framework](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/start.overview)

Вот так выглядит класс, который отвечает за получение записей блога из базы: [Post.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/demos/blog/protected/models/Post.php). Класс сгенерирован автоматически и дополнен методами, которые нужны только для записей блога. Как видишь, там даже метода `save()` нет - сохраняется через родительский класс.

Вот так выглядит контролер - класс, который обрабатывает URL вида `http://хост/blog/` : [PostController.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/demos/blog/protected/controllers/PostController.php). Он тоже сгенерирован автоматически и дополнен методами, которые нужны только для записей блога. Например, метод `actionView` вызывается, когда обращаются к одной странице блога `http://хост/blog/1345`

Вот таким кодом выводится текст одной записи блога [views/post/view.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/demos/blog/protected/views/post/view.php) и при этом этот код встроен внутрь другого  [views/layouts/main.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/demos/blog/protected/views/layouts/main.php) и в целом получается аккуратно [оформленная страница блога](http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/blog/index.php/post/1/Welcome%21)

Фреймворков куча. Посмотри [Laravel](http://laravel.ru/) , [Yii](http://yiiframework.ru/) или [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/).